# Visual marker of mouse clicks using Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouse, screenshot

I am creating a screen recorder software using Java. Almost 80% work has been completed. Now I need to create a visual marker of mouse clicks using Java. So that I can see in the playback video that where the mouse has been clicked. How can I do that?

Does anyone have any code example?

Comment: This will depend a lot on how you recording the screen.  There is no native way for Java to monitor the mouse outside of the application space, so you will need to have a JNI solution to monitor the mouse clicks

Comment: This sounds like a fun project using `List<Point>` to record clicks in a `MouseAdapter` and a `javax.swing.Timer` for playback. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows any problems you encounter.

Comment: How can i do that using JNI or JNA ?  Please tell me if you know any way to do that ??   @MadProgrammer

Comment: How can i do that using JNI or JNA ?  Please tell me if you know any way to do that ??  @trashgod

Comment: You may want to update your question to reflect this (platform-specific) requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple.  Read the point where the mouse is clicked by the user with getX() and getY() methods of MouseListener.  At the point, draw a oval with drawOval() methods of java.awt.Graphics class.   Try the following code which I am sure solves your problem.

```
import java.awt.*;   
import java.awt.event.*;

// no window closing code
public class MouseXY extends Frame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener  
{
          int x , y;
          String str =" ";
          public MouseXY()  
          {
                 setSize(500, 500);
                 setVisible(true); 
                 addMouseListener(this);                // register both the listeners with frame
                 addMouseMotionListener(this);                              
           }                                            // override the 5 abstract methods of ML
           public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)   
           { 
                  setBackground(Color.green);
                  x = e.getX();
                  y = e.getY();
                  str ="Mouse Entered";
                  repaint();
           }                                                                   
           public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)    
           {
                  setBackground(Color.red);
                  x = e.getX();
                  y = e.getY();
                  str ="Mouse Exited";
                  repaint();
           }
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
           {
                  setBackground(Color.gray);
                  x = e.getX();
                  y = e.getY();
                  str ="Mouse Clicked";
                  repaint();
           }
           public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)   
           {
                  setBackground(Color.blue);
                  x = e.getX();
                  y = e.getY();
                  str ="Mouse Released";
                  repaint();
           }
           public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)   
           {
               setBackground(Color.lightGray);
               x = e.getX();
               y = e.getY();
               str ="Mouse pressed";
               repaint();
          }                                                       // override the 2 abstract methods of MML
          public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
          {
               setBackground(Color.magenta);
               x = e.getX(); 
               y = e.getY();
               str ="Mouse Dragged";
               repaint();
          }
          public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)  
          {
               setBackground(Color.yellow);
               x = e.getX();
               y = e.getY();
               str = "Mouse Moved";
               repaint();
          }
          public void paint(Graphics g)  
          {
               g.setColor(Color.blue);
               g.fillOval(x , y , 10 , 10);
               g.drawString(x +", "+ y , x , y);
               g.drawString(str , x , y -10);             // to draw the string above y coordinate
    }                              
    public static void main(String args[ ])   
    {
               new MouseXY();
    }
```

}

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. But your solution is application specific. Your provided code worked only within the JFrame(within the application space). But i don't want to do that.  When you record your desktop screen using "faststone capture" or "snagit" then you don't interact only with that app. you interact with the whole desktop. So i want to monitor the mouse outside of the application space. Someone has already gave a comment here saying that there is no native way for Java to monitor the mouse outside of the application space. So do you know any other way to do what i want ??

Comment: Update your question to reflect this intent.